# Ongoing problem with flooding in a finished basement - Need advice

Tags: water, basement, flooding

We’ve had an ongoing problem with basement flooding in a finished basement that was added onto an existing structure a few years ago.  We initially put in french drains to catch water that runs downhill on the downhill slope towards our retaining wall - but it didn’t fix the problem.  And more recently we did excavation work to improve grading and install proper perimeter drainage.  And now we’ve found that didn't fix the problem either.

Here are pictures:  https://imgur.com/a/AgoqOwF.  The part of the structure with siding is single story but the brick portion is 2 levels - so the foundation elevation is on 2 levels.  There is only one place that floods in the lower level basement which is where that retaining wall meets the building.   The water just slowly seeps in where the wall and basement floor meet.  The gutters are working and we’re confident we now have a perimeter drain that’s installed correctly.  So now, we’re suspecting we have a wet weather spring that’s causing the flooding.

We’ve noticed for a long time now that the box that has the handle to turn on/off the frost proof faucet floods during heavy rains.  That box has a very heavy lid (probably weighs 5 or more pounds) which my husband says gets partially lifted when it rains hard.  You can see standing water in the box now and we expect it will take several days of dry weather to fully dissipate.  He also says that when we only had the single story structure (the 2 story addition hadn't been built yet), he could see a lot of water come out from under a concrete pad that used to be there (in the same area where it’s currently flooding) during heavy rains.  So maybe that’s been our problem all along?

So we aren't sure where to go from here.  Is there a way to test for a spring?  Maybe there’s some sort of water catch basin that could be installed in that area that we could drain or pump away?  We know we could call one of those basement companies that guarantee a dry basement but it seems like fixing the problem outside (and at the source) would be best.  Is there something completely different that we should consider?

Comment: do you have a sump pump? that can lower the water table around the house, giving water somewhere to go before backing up.

Comment: No.  Should be look at one for the outside??  That's one thing we are wondering if possible.

Comment: Was any water proofing placed on the foundation.  It might not stop the flooding completely but it should help a lot if none is there.

Comment: Yes, foundation walls were waterproofed with some kind of paint substance when built.

Comment: I've not seen a sump pump used outside, but if the water is just seeping into the basement, one should help with that. Rare torrents would probably still pose a problem with a sump, but it would add a big buffer to the most common situations becoming a problem. I would also consider improving the retaining wall, maybe adding some kind of water tight membrane/treatment behind it and even under it a bit so that the water dams around your house.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm working on an old house now, with similar problems. I did a French drain and sloped the yard, but did not help. Finally installed a sump pump 24" below the grade of the basement slab. That solved the issue. During the summer the pump well is dry, but every spring the basement would flood 12" without the sump pump, just from the water table coming up from under the slab.

Comment: 12"....wow!  Your sump was installed inside or outside?  Sump pumps are new territory to us.

Comment: Sump pump installed inside of the basement. Had to cut the slab.

Comment: This is the most likely path to fix it. Cut a hole in the floor, dig a two foot well, add a sump, add a pump, install a lid over it so you can still use the floor and also get to the pump for service and replacement.

Comment: Sump pumps are _very_ common here in the Midwest. Even brand new houses, with all the latest waterproofing technology are built with them from new, @Mevrowka. This is a known and acceptable solution.